# IF condition with logical operators in JOLT mapping

Tags: jolt

Is there a way to use if condition with AND / OR in JOLT?
I have a json where i need to check two field values and then set the mapping.
E.g

```
**Input:**
{
  "oldStatus":"NEW",
  "newStatus":"OPEN"
}
```

The JOLT logic should be doing something like this:
if(oldStatus == "NEW" AND newStatus=="OPEN")
then
status = "In Progress"

```
**Expected Output**
{
  "status":"In Progress"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "fullStat": "=concat(@(1,oldStatus),@(1,newStatus))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fullStat": {
        "NEWOPEN": {
          "#In Progress": "status"
        },
        "*": {
          "#Not In Progress": "status"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```